# IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005).System.Data while data adapter Fill()

Tags: c#, .net, excel-2007

I'm trying to get data from CSV file , by using  fill() method  i got a exception idk why it arise,please review code  and suggest  optimistic answer.note that if parameter "s" doesn't have any space means it works fine. if it have space means how to overcome that,don't suggest temporary rename and all.

```
/// <summary>
/// Import Function For CSV Delimeted File
/// </summary>
/// <param name="s">File Name</param>
private DataTable Import4csv(string s)
{
    string file = Path.GetFileName(s);
    string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(s);
    string sConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
                             + "Data Source=\"" + dir + "\\\";"
                             + "Extended Properties=\"text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited\"";
    try
    {
        var objConn = new OleDbConnection(sConnection);
        objConn.Open();
        var ds = new DataSet();
        var da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " + file, sConnection);
        da.Fill(ds);        // getting exception on this line.
        objConn.Close();
        return ds.Tables[0];
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine(ex.Message + ex.Source);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM `" + file + "`", sConnection);
```

near the tilde key..

Comment: fixed it, you need to use ` character before and after of file name that has spaces

Answer (score 5):

I have faced the same issue, but was able to overcome it by enclosing the suspect word in square brackets.

In my case, it was a field name which I used in "Where" condition i.e.;

```
select * from tblDetail where [Section] = 'Operations'
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case replacing the whole field names in query by `*` solved the issue.