# Given string array of column names, how do I read a .csv file to a DataTable?

Tags: c#, linq, csv

Assume I have a .csv file with 70 columns, but only 5 of the columns are what I need. I want to be able to pass a method a string array of the columns names that I want, and for it to return a datatable.

```
private void method(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string[] columns =
    {
        @"Column21",
        @"Column48"
    };
    DataTable myDataTable = Get_DT(columns);
}

public DataTable Get_DT(string[] columns) {
    DataTable ret = new DataTable();
    if (columns.Length > 0) 
    {
        foreach (string column in columns)
        {
              ret.Columns.Add(column);
        }

        string[] csvlines = File.ReadAllLines(@"path to csv file");
        csvlines = csvlines.Skip(1).ToArray();  //ignore the columns in the first line of the csv file

        //this is where i need help... i want to use linq to read the fields
        //of the each row with only the columns name given in the string[] 
        //named columns
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: I haven't tried this but if the CSV file has a header record - then you may be able to import using OleDb & select just the columns you want. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813607/parsing-csv-using-oledb-using-c-sharp

Comment: Looks like a great idea @PaulF. Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813607/parsing-csv-using-oledb-using-c-sharp).

Comment: If the CSV hasn't got a header file, then you can provide a "schema.ini" file in the same folder to specify field names & types. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/schema-ini-file-text-file-driver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the first line of the file, `line.Split(',')` (or whatever your delimiter is), then get the index of each column name and store that.
Then for each other line, again do a `var values = line.Split(',')`, then get the values from the columns.

Quick and dirty version:

```
string[] csvlines = File.ReadAllLines(@"path to csv file");
//select the indices of the columns we want
var cols = csvlines[0].Split(',').Select((val,i) => new { val, i }).Where(x => columns.Any(c => c == x.val)).Select(x => x.i).ToList();
//now go through the remaining lines
foreach (var line in csvlines.Skip(1))
{
    var line_values = line.Split(',').ToList();
    var dt_values = line_values.Where(x => cols.Contains(line_values.IndexOf(x)));
    //now do something with the values you got for this row, add them to your datatable
}
```

Comment: The point of this version was to make sure Tim could use dynamic column headers, passed in an array as he had asked.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/

Think Reading individual fields is what you are looking for

```
var csv = new CsvReader( textReader );
while( csv.Read() )
{
    var intField = csv.GetField<int>( 0 );
    var stringField = csv.GetField<string>( 1 );
    var boolField = csv.GetField<bool>( "HeaderName" );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can easily do this without writing much code.

Exceldatareader is an awesome dll for that, it will directly as a datable from the excel sheet with just one method.

**here is the links for example:**http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/using-iexceldatareader1

http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/

Hope it was useful kindly let me know your thoughts or feedbacks

Thanks

Karthik

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = File.ReadAllLines(@"path to csv file");
// the expenses row
var query = data.Single(d => d[0] == "Expenses");
//third column
int column21 = 3;
return query[column21];
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated a library like CsvReader can be used for this. As for linq, I don't think its suitable for this kind of job.

I haven't tested this but it should get you through

```
using (TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(filePath))
{
    using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(textReader))
    {
        var headers = csvReader.FieldHeaders;
        for (int rowIndex = 0; csvReader.Read(); rowIndex++)
        {
            var dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();
            for (int chosenColumnIndex = 0; chosenColumnIndex < columns.Count(); chosenColumnIndex++)
            {
                for (int headerIndex = 0; headerIndex < headers.Length; headerIndex++)
                {
                    if (headers[headerIndex] == columns[chosenColumnIndex])
                    {
                        dataRow[chosenColumnIndex] = csvReader.GetField<string>(headerIndex);
                    }
                }
            }
            dataTable.Rows.InsertAt(dataRow, rowIndex);
        }
    }
}
```