# What is a correct format of OleDB connection string for csv file

Tags: winforms, csv, oledb

I encounter an error (`'\csvFile.csv' is not a correct path.Check if the path name is correct`)while trying to load csv file to `datagridview` using `OleDB connection`:

```
        MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = '\\csvFile.csv'; Extended Properties = \"text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited\"");
```

What is correct format of this connection string?File is located within project's folder.

In different window I'm loading the same csv file using StreamReader. It works fine.Would that influence the OleDB connection?

Comment: Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=c:\txtFilesFolder\;
Extended Properties="text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited"    .... (found that with google)

Comment: @nabuchodonossor Of course I did my research before asking this question..Unfortunately this solution didn't work neither.

Comment: "\csvFile.csv": do you have your csv in your root directory?

Comment: @nabuchodonossor yes

Comment: [Parsing CSV using OleDb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813607/parsing-csv-using-oledb-using-c-sharp?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: Forgot to mention. If you want to a *catalog* type of access, you need to use a `schema.ini` file: [Schema.ini File (Text File Driver)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/schema-ini-file-text-file-driver?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Thanks @Jimi.Now I'm getting error:Wrong parameter used.I guess it's better if I start all over again.

Comment: Start from ditching this => `'\\csvFile.csv'` and using a string variable in a `string.Format()` or `$"{ }"` an interpolated construct. `The Extended Properties` part is also malformed.